# Add item if it isn't already in the cart, increase its quantity when it does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I'm using React context to add products to the cart with simple logic, and I'm using `useReducer` hook for adding items to the cart.

With Redux Toolkit the logic is easy to implement, firstly please check my redux logic:

```
const cartItemSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: {
        items: [],
        totalQuantity: 0,
        totalAmount: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        addProduct(state, action) {
            const newCartItems = action.payload; //items from dispatch object
            const existingItem = state.items.find((el) => el.id === newCartItems.id);
            state.totalQuantity++;
            if (!existingItem) {
                state.items.push({
                    id: newCartItems.id,
                    quantity: 1,
                    title: newCartItems.title,
                    price: newCartItems.price,
                    image: newCartItems.image,
                    totalPrice: newCartItems.price,
                });
            } else {
                existingItem.quantity++;
            }
        },
    }

 })
```

Now **HOW CAN I DO THAT SAME THING WITH REACT CONTEXT**? How to get the array that is matched with the id and add the item to the cart while dispatching it, here I'm trying to put that in context:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const CartItemContext = React.createContext();

const CartContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
        (state, action) => {
            if (action.type === "ADD-ITEM") {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    items: state.items.find((el) => el.id === action.payload.id),
                    totalQuantity: state.totalQuantity++,
                };
            }
        },
        {
            items: [],
            totalPrice: 0,
            totalQuantity: 0,
        }
    );
    return (
        <CartItemContext.Provider
            value={{
                items: state.items,
                totalPrice: state.totalPrice,
                totalQuantity: state.totalQuantity,
                dispatch,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </CartItemContext.Provider>
    );
};

export { CartItemContext, CartContextProvider };
```

And here when I click the `add to cart button` in my component:

```
export default function BookItems(props) {
    const { id, title, price, image } = props;

    const cartItemsCtx = useContext(CartItemContext);
    const { dispatch } = cartItemsCtx;

    const addToCartHandler = () => {
        dispatch({
            type: "ADD-ITEM",
            payload: {
                id, title, price, image 
            },
        });
    };
    return (
        <div className={classes.product__item}>                     
            <Link href={`/products/${id}`}>
                <Image src={image} alt={title} className={classes.image} fill />
                <h3>{title}</h3>
            </Link>
            <div className={classes.bottom}>
                <p>${price}</p>
                <button onClick={addToCartHandler}>Add to cart</button>
            </div>              
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohit! Check my answer with its latest edit and let me know please :)

Comment: Glad I could help Mohit. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below, with the help of the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). If there is an existing one, change its quantity and add it to `state.items`; otherwise, add the new one.

```js
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from "react";

// I moved it out here for readability
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "ADD-ITEM") {
    const newCartItems = action.payload;
    let existingItem = state.items.find((el) => el.id === newCartItems.id);
    if (existingItem) {
      existingItem = { ...existingItem, quantity: existingItem.quantity + 1 };
    }
    return {
      ...state,
      items: !existingItem ? [...state.items, newCartItems] : [...state.items, existingItem],
      totalQuantity: state.totalQuantity++,
    };
  }
};

// I moved it out here for readability
initialState = {
  items: [],
  totalPrice: 0,
  totalQuantity: 0,
};

const CartItemContext = createContext();

const CartContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <CartItemContext.Provider
      value={{
        items: state.items,
        totalPrice: state.totalPrice,
        totalQuantity: state.totalQuantity,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartItemContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { CartItemContext, CartContextProvider };
```